# Load child Ag-gird next to parent grid on same page

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a requirement where I need to load child grid on the click of parent grid cell.
I am able to do that ,however I need to show them next to each other, **So when Child grid renders parent grid adjust its width automatically.
I** tried something like this below 
Parent Component Html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <ag-grid-angular  style="width: 50%; height: 200px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
        </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <child-grid-component-selector [showChildGrid]="showMe"></child-grid-component-selector>
    </div>
</div>
```

Parent component CSS

```
.row {
    display: flex;
  }

  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 500px;
  }
```

Child Component Html

```
<div *ngIf="showChildGrid">
                    <ag-grid-angular
                    style="width: 50%; height: 200px;"
                    class="ag-theme-balham"
                    [rowData]="rowData"
                    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
                    </ag-grid-angular>
                </div>
```

I took reference from here: [side by side grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687114/how-to-display-two-grids-side-by-side-using-angular-6-ag-grid) but its working to show the grids side by side but not adjusting when the child grid appears/disappears.
Please let me know if my question requires further explanation.
Thanks,

Edit: I need a solution of this question, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What seems to be the problem/what is not working? Your code looks fine to me. Check out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-spnatl) StackBlitz of your code.

Comment: Hi @Viqas thanks for taking your time out ,it is working as in 2 grid is shown adjacent to each other, but what I want is, I want the parent to adjust its width as an when child gird appears in the page. can we do that ?